# Several close placeholders in postgres prepared statement

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm using Spring JbdcTemplate with Postgres.

Stuck with a problem cause of the Postrgres JDBC internal prepared statement implemetation

My query string is:

```
private static final String SELECT_ALL_PARTIALLY =
            "SELECT login, added FROM admin ORDER BY ? ? OFFSET ? LIMIT ?";
```

And I want to use it like:

```
List matches = getJdbcTemplate().query(SELECT_ALL_PARTIALLY,
                (new Object[]{
                    column, // "login" or "added"
                    order,  // "asc" or "desc"
                    offset, 
                    limit
                }),
                new RowMapper() {
                    ...
```

The problem is with a `...ORDER BY ? ? OFFSET...`

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$2"
  Position: 61
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:648) ...
```

How can I separate this two placeholders or something?

Answer (score 1):

Postgres doesn't allow you to specify ordering direction as a parameter. You need to create different query strings for `asc` and `desc` order and choose one of them to execute.

Comment: Oh. Are you sure? Thats pretty bad. What if I need to order over multiple columns, so I need to have a query for each combination of asc/desc paramters? Is there some workaround for this?

Comment: @user976426: Column name can be specified as a parameter, only direction can't.

Comment: @axtavt Are you positive re: placeholders working with columns? PG placeholders appear to only hold values (not column names). What data type would a column name be, text? To be clear, it would be great if this does work.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-prepare.html 

However given a table `users` with an `id` column of `integer` type, executing a statement like `PREPARE bar1 AS select * from users ORDER BY $1; EXECUTE bar1(id);` gets you "column "id" does not exist", at least. The same goes for `EXECUTE bar1("id")`.